# How to close/dismiss/hide a menu by clicking on a button in an embedded view from within it, in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I have created a menu app, using Swift, for Mac OS, within which, a custom view is the only menu item. There's a plus button on this custom view, which opens a window that has a textfield.

When I click on the plus button, the window appears, but the menu does not disappear. The textfield is also not focused. When I type one letter, the letter is not shown in the textfield, but the menu disappears, and the textfield is focused and ready to receive entry.

I want to have the custom view or menu disappear and have the textfield ready to receive keystrokes when I click on the plus button, not after I press an extra key.

How may I achieve that? What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```swift
// CustomView.swift

    var customWindow: CustomWindow!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        customWindow = CustomWindow()
    }

    @IBAction func plusButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
        customWindow.showWindow(nil)
}



// CustomWindow.swift

    override var windowNibName : NSNib.Name? {
        return NSNib.Name("CustomWindow")
    }


    override func windowDidLoad() {

        super.windowDidLoad()

        self.window?.center()
        self.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        self.window?.level = .mainMenu + 100
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)

        if customTextField.acceptsFirstResponder {
            customTextField.window?.makeFirstResponder(customTextField)
        }


// CustomMenuContoller.swift

let statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)


    @IBOutlet weak var CustomMenu: NSMenu!
    @IBOutlet weak var customView: CustomView!
    var customMenuItem: NSMenuItem!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        customMenuItem = CustomMenu.item(withTitle: "TheMenu")
        customMenuItem.view = customView
        statusBarItem.menu = CustomMenu
}
```

Comment: CustomMenu.cancelTracking()

Comment: Thanks. But the CustomMenu is not accessible from the plusButtonClicked action, which is where I might want to call it.

Comment: Why is it not accessible when you create it as an IBOutlet?

Comment: Well, the plusButtonClicked is limited to its own context, which is the controller within which, it resides and all the public variables. CustomMenu in itself is not public, but its containing variable, which is public, is accessible. 
So inspired by your suggestion, I called statusBarItem.menu?.cancelTracking() to plusButtonClicked action, and it works! Thanks.

Comment: you can try using a callback function

Comment: Did you try `NSView` method `enclosingMenuItem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [El Tomato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1824524/el-tomato)'s comment, I found the solution.

Given the fact that the `plusButtonClicked` is limited to its own context, which is the controller within which it resides and all the public variables, I could not call a method on `CustomMenu` from it. Because `CustomMenu` in itself is not public. But its containing variable `statusBarItem.menu`, is public and accessible from all the other views. So I added `statusBarItem.menu?.cancelTracking()` to `plusButtonClicked` action and it works.